# How to stop TestNG from running after a test fail

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am trying to write a test method in TestNG, that after it fails - the entire test suite will stop running.

```
@Test
public void stopTestingIfThisFailed() throws Exception
{
    someTestStesp();
    if (softAsserter.isOneFailed()) {
        asserter.fail("stopTestingIfThisFailed test Failed");
        throw new Exception("Test can't continue, fail here!");
    }
}
```

The exception is being thrown, but other test methods are running.

How to solve this?

Comment: Why would you cancel the run of the entire suite if one test fails?

Comment: It means a show stopper, if this test fails there is no point in continue the rest of the test suite run.

Comment: But aren't your other tests important too? What if one of your other tests finds a show stopper also? If you stop after the first, you only find one instead of all the issues.

Comment: That's exactly what I need to do: stop the tests from running if this specific test fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like this: after a test that mustn't fail fails - I'm writing data to a temporary text file.

Later, in the next test I added code in the @BeforeClass that checks that data in the former mentioned text file. If a show stopper was found I'm killing the current process.

If a test the "can't" fail actually fails:

```
 public static void saveShowStopper() {

    try {
        General.createFile("ShowStopper","tempShowStopper.txt");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The @BeforeClass validating code:

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void beforeClass(ITestContext testContext, @Optional String step, @Optional String suiteLoopData,
        @Optional String group) throws Exception
{
    boolean wasShowStopperFound = APIUtils.loadShowStopper();
    if (wasShowStopperFound){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `dependsOnMethods` or `dependsOnGroups` annotation parameter in your other test methods:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"stopTestingIfThisFailed"})
public void testAnotherTestMehtod()  {

}
```

[JavaDoc of the `dependsOnMethods` parameter](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/7.0.0-beta4):

> The list of methods this method depends on. There is no guarantee on the order on which the methods depended upon will be run, but you are guaranteed that all these methods will be run before the test method that contains this annotation is run. Furthermore, **if any of these methods was not a SUCCESS, this test method will not be run and will be flagged as a SKIP**. If some of these methods have been overloaded, all the overloaded versions will be run.

See https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods

Comment: What if there are dozen of methods in class?

Comment: Sadly you'll have to add this to every test method, if the methods are within the same test class. This can also be set on class level, but I'm unsure, if this is really supported by TestNG. The examples in the documentation only use this on method level.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you expect (there is no direct support for this in TestNG). You can create `ShowStopperException` which is thrown in `@Test` and then in your `ITestListener` implementation ([see docs](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners)) you can call `System.exit(1 (or whatever number))` when you find this exeption in result but there will be no report and in general it's not good practice. Second option is to have some base class which is parent of all test classes and some context variable which will handle `ShowStopperException` in `@BeforeMethod` in parent class and throw `SkipException` so workflow can be like:

```
test passed
test passed
showstopper exception in some test
test skipped
test skipped
test skipped
...
```

Answer (score -1):

It behaves if you throw a specific exception, `SkipException`, from the `@BeforeSuite` setup method.

See (possible dupe)
[TestNG - How to force end the entire test suite from the BeforeSuite annotation if a condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410383/testng-how-to-force-end-the-entire-test-suite-from-the-beforesuite-annotation)

If you want to do it from an arbitrary test, it doesn't appear there is a framework mechanism. But you could always flip a flag, and check that flag in the `@BeforeTest` setup method. Before you jump to that, maybe have a think if you could check once before the whole suite runs, and just abort there (ie `@BeforeSuite`).