# How to execute tests by queue with Factory dataprovider

Tags: java, testng

I try to execute tests by queue in the following structure:

```java
public class SomeTest {

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] dp(){
        return new Object[][]{{"dataprovider-1"}, {"dataprovider-2"}};
    }

    private String data;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
    public SomeTest(String data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass(){
        System.out.println("Data from beforeClass: " + data);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("Data from test1: " + data);
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "test1")
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("Data from test2: " + data);
    }


    @AfterClass
    public void ac(){
        System.out.println("Data from afterClass: " + data);
    }
    
}
```

I expected, after constructor initialized all methods will be called before other constructors initialized:

- @BeforeClass
- tests (methods)
- @AfterClass

So I expected something like:

```
//constructor 1
Data from beforeClass: dataprovider-1
Data from test1: dataprovider-1
Data from test2: dataprovider-1
Data from afterClass: dataprovider-1
//constructor 2
Data from beforeClass: dataprovider-2
Data from test1: dataprovider-2
Data from test2: dataprovider-2
Data from afterClass: dataprovider-2
```

But actually I get following result:

```
Data from beforeClass: dataprovider-1
Data from test1: dataprovider-1
Data from beforeClass: dataprovider-2
Data from test1: dataprovider-2
Data from test2: dataprovider-1
Data from afterClass: dataprovider-1
Data from test2: dataprovider-2
Data from afterClass: dataprovider-2
```

How to execute tests in order - all tests for each DataProvider value?

Comment: Why would you want the tests to be executed in a specific order? In general it is bad practice to rely on test execution order and such dependencies should be avoided.

Comment: @dpr for example CRUD operations testing. The Create test should be executed before Delete,

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220934/4323935 However introducing dependencies between tests always has some taste and you should probably try to extract the common logic to be reused by multiple tests. There are probably some valid exceptions but as said this is something that should be avoided in general.